# ForbiddenAttributesError in ruby on rails when update_attributes use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am createing simple ruby blog app I am updating a post but it's showing thi type error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyi3k.png)

```
        def edit
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
            if @post
                puts "******************dd*********************"
                puts params[:post]
                puts "**************************************"
                @post.update_attributes(params[:post])


                redirect_to post_path, :notice => "you post  has been updated"
            else
                render "edit"
            end
        end
```

but when I  using this

```
        @post.update_attributes({"title"=>"2nd", "body"=>"this is second post body", "category_id"=>"2"})
```

it is work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [strong parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), Rails prevent you from assigning unfiltered params coming from outside world for [security reasons](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/security.html#mass-assignment).

```
def update
  # ...
  @post.update_attributes(post_params)
  # ...
end

# ...

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes should be whitelisted for updating.

Below is the code:

```
        def edit
            @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
           @post = Post.find(params[:id])
           if @post
              @post.update_attributes(post_params)
              redirect_to post_path, :notice => "you post  has been updated"
           else
              render "edit"
           end
        end

   private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ForbiddenAttributesError.html) is only raised if you pass unsanitized objects to the record update call.

```
@post.update_attributes(params[:post]) # This would be an issue

Post.where(params[:post]) # This would not

@post.update_attributes(post_params) # Neither would this

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id)
end
```